# passing in variables to eval

Tags: python, dynamic, eval

I am trying to dynamic run ta-lib indicators using eval, I build the below code:

```
sy=eval("talib."+str(i)+"("+str(df['DFF'].values)+","+str(X)+")")
```

where i is the ta-lib indicator, df['dff'] is a data frame holding prices and X is 5

I get the below error:

```
talib.MAMA([1.42 1.42 1.42 1.42 1.42 1.42 1.42 1.42 1.42 1.42 1.42 1.42 1.42 1.42
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not exactly sure what I am doing wrong here, can anyone help?

Comment: Why are you using `eval()` in the first place? That's a _very_ dangerous function that should only be used very carefully when there is no other option. This shouldn't be a regular programming strategy, by any stretch.

Comment: A list in Python needs a comma between each adjacent pair of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely listen to @chris.  Using `eval` should be an absolute last resort. You are creating a massive security hole in your program.

If you have an object `talib`, and you want to call some method whose name is stored in a variable `method_name`, use something like:

```
getattr(talib, method_name)(...arguments...)
```

Can you explain a little bit better what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: This is great I was not aware of this approach, thanks for this!